# Page view permission to authenticated users only in MEAN js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean

I'm taking a look at MEAN js and I just started their tutorial that has user and articles.

Once signed up I can correctly create an article, good.

If I log out, coming back to the /article page if I try to create an article it redirect me correctly to the login page but, how can I prevent the page to be viewed if the user is not logged in?

There is nothing special in the code, it is the original MEAN app: http://meanjs.org/

This is the routing for articles:

```
'use strict';

// Setting up route
angular.module('articles').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Articles state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('app.listArticles', {
            url: '/articles',
            templateUrl: 'modules/articles/views/list-articles.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('app.createArticle', {
            url: '/articles/create',
            templateUrl: 'modules/articles/views/create-article.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('app.viewArticle', {
            url: '/articles/:articleId',
            templateUrl: 'modules/articles/views/view-article.client.view.html',
            controller: 'ArticlesController'
        }).
        state('app.editArticle', {
            url: '/articles/:articleId/edit',
            templateUrl: 'modules/articles/views/edit-article.client.view.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

At the moment the only solution I found by my self is to add the code below in the article controller:

```
if ($scope.authentication.user === "") {
    $location.path('home/');
}
```

But I don't think it is the best solution to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a resolve method on the state and check every time the user visits if they're auth'd. Not sure if ui-router includes resolve though.

E.g.

```
.state( "app.profile", { 
templateUrl:  "/build/templates/profile.html", 
controller: "ProfileCtrl",
resolve: requireUser } )


    var requireUser = { User: [ "$location", "$rootScope", "$q", "API", "Session",
    function ( $location, $rootScope, $q, API, Session )
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

                if( Session.get.authToken() )
                {
                    if( Session.get.user() )
                    {
                        deferred.resolve( $rootScope.user );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $location.path( "/login" );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    deferred.reject( "No user token" );
                    $location.path( "/login" );
                }

            return deferred.promise;

        } ] };
```

Comment: Awesome, I created an helper with this and it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: HI new to MEAN stack, loving it but struggling. I am trying to do the same thing. I added resolve:requireUser to the .client.routes.js and the the rest to clien.config.js which stops users accessing the page who have not authenticated but authenitcated users can't log in either. I get no error in my log if you have any insight into the issue that would be amaxing.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at a similar problem, I wanted to open certain routes only to authenticated users and stop others having access to them.

I created a new controller called AuthenticateController:

```
angular.module('projects').controller('AuthenticateController',      ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Projects',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Projects) {
   $scope.authentication = Authentication;
   if ($scope.authentication.user === '') {
    $location.path('home/');
   }
   }
```

And added it into the controller.js file for that module.

This has some (Very) basic code that checks to see if the user is authenticated and if not chucks them back to the home page. I then bound the route to this controller in the routes.js:

```
    state('createProject', {
    url: '/projects/create',
    templateUrl: 'modules/projects/views/create-project.client.view.html',
    controller: 'AuthenticateController'
}).
```

This solution seems to work however I am new to MEAN (my first week) so if anyone has a better solution or could elaborate then suggestions not only welcome but encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use, ng-show="authentication.user" on nav in header.client.view.html file!